# Investpy module

Tags: python, trading

My code:

```
import investpy
print(investpy.__version__)

df = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock='AAPL',
                                        country='United States',
                                        from_date='01/01/2010',
                                        to_date='01/01/2020')
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
1.0.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\90551\Desktop\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\investpy\stocks.py", line 664, in get_stock_historical_data
    raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: ERR#0015: error 503, try again later.
```

I dont understand eror. I searched but couldn't find a solution.I would be grateful if you could help

Answer (score 0):

It usually simply means that the service you are trying to access is currently down. If you wait some time – as the message suggests – and then try again, it should work. (Might take minutes, hours, or even days, depending on the issue.)

Comment: postgresql is running on my computer but yes I can't reach pgadmin on my localhost right now but the application is running and I can see the interface how can I fix this?